# C / how to listen on multiple UDP ports

Tags: c, sockets

The application I am working on should be able to listen to multiple (right now 4) port numbers. Do I need to create a socket for every of these ports, like:

```
if((sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("error: could not create UDP socket\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

bzero(&sock_addr, sizeof(sock_addr));
sock_addr.sin_family    = AF_INET;
sock_addr.sin_port      = htons(port1);
sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr   = inet_addr(INADDR_ANY);

if(bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &sock_addr, sock_len) < 0) {
    perror("error: could not bind UDP socket to AU\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Or is there a more elegant way to do that? Also I read about the `select()` statement, would that be something I should use? The reason I want to listen on several ports is quite simple, it should identify the application I am communicating with. E.g. one application per port.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

// UPDATE:
How should I set up the one socket per port?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need separate sockets for each pair of (IP,port) numbers that you wish to communicate through.

And yes, you can absolutely use the `select()` function (it's not a "statement" which implies being somehow part of the language, it's just a function in the library) to service the multiple sockets once you've set them all up.

Comment: Can you give me a brief introduction in how to set up the sockets and their corresponding ports? Whenever I try to set up one socket per port, I get an `: Address already in use` error.

Comment: it might be that you're trying to bind your socket with a port which is already in use by another application. For details and examples on C sockets, have a look here: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

Comment: Setting SO_REUSEADDR also helps a lot against ports staying in use -- like after a program crash.