# Linux C UDP Socket - Listening on multiple ports

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I am trying to get a server to listen for incoming UDP packets in C using Linux. From what I have read this can be accomplished by creating 2 `socket()`'s, and binding them to the same address (NULL, for local machine default) but with 2 different ports. From here most of the explanations fall off or go on to explain using `listen()`, which I thought was meant for TCP packets. How can I get the server to listen on 2 ports simultaneously without halting the program execution while it waits to receive from one port before the next. Ie:

```
recvfrom(sockfd, etc etc etc);
recvfrom(sockfd1, etc etc etc);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Also this is being done via single process.

Comment: Use two threads, one for each port.

Comment: Check out 'poll()' and 'select()' which can wait on multiple sockets.

Comment: Doing that now. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: You don't need two sockets. One is enough.

Comment: @EJP: not if you really need to receive packets on more than one port, depending on the protocol. For instance, stereo RTP audio uses 2 UDP ports, one for each channel of audio. A socket may be bound to multiple IPs at a time (via INADDR_ANY or equivalent), but can be bound to only one port at a time, thus requiring multiple sockets for multiple ports.

Comment: I know this is super old, but I would really appreciate any kind of solution you came to as I'm facing a similar situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C / how to listen on multiple UDP ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597636/c-how-to-listen-on-multiple-udp-ports)